# How to change the styles of ListItem element with the "onclick" event?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

My goal is when I click on a ListItem, it should change the `background-color` and `text: "line-through"`. And then, if I click again, these changes should be canceled.
But it happens very strangely for me. I just can't understand why `ListItem` changes `background-color` only after I click to any place of the window? And why text into ListItem becomes crossed out only after I move pointer beyond the element

```
const styles = () => ({
  listItem: {
    borderRadius: "1em"
  },

  listItemDone: {
    borderRadius: "1em",
    backgroundColor: "#F6F6E8",
    textDecoration: "line-through"
  },

  iconButton: {
    padding: 5
  },

  important: {
    color: "#00ACE9",
    fontWeight: "bold"
  }
});

class TodoListItem extends Component {
  state = {
    done: false
  };

  onClickItem = () => {
    this.setState({
      done: !this.state.done
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { label, important = false, classes } = this.props;
    const { done } = this.state;

    return (
      <ListItem
        onClick={this.onClickItem}
        className={done ? classes.listItemDone : classes.listItem}
        button
        divider
      >
        <ListItemText
          primary={label}
          classes={{ primary: important ? classes.important : "" }}
        />
      </ListItem>
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Edit v8ojkj2qzy]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Whenever you are trying to override Material-UI styles and it isn't working like you would expect, the best resource is the source code. Here is the URL for the `ListItem` source code: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/packages/material-ui/src/ListItem/ListItem.js. For the most part, you only need to look at the `styles` variable near the top of the source file.

Below I've copied all of the portions of the `styles` variable that deal with `backgroundColor` and `textDecoration`:

```
export const styles = theme => ({
  /* Styles applied to the (normally root) `component` element. May be wrapped by a `container`. */
  root: {
    textDecoration: 'none',
    '&$selected, &$selected:hover, &$selected:focus': {
      backgroundColor: theme.palette.action.selected,
    },
  },
  /* Styles applied to the inner `component` element if `button={true}`. */
  button: {
    transition: theme.transitions.create('background-color', {
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.shortest,
    }),
    '&:hover': {
      textDecoration: 'none',
      backgroundColor: theme.palette.action.hover,
      // Reset on touch devices, it doesn't add specificity
      '@media (hover: none)': {
        backgroundColor: 'transparent',
      },
    },
    '&:focus': {
      backgroundColor: theme.palette.action.hover,
    },
  },
  /* Styles applied to the root element if `selected={true}`. */
  selected: {},
});
```

The main styles causing difficulty are the `button` hover and focus styles. In order to override these successfully without resorting to "!important", you need to have the appropriate CSS specificity.

The following seems to do the trick:

```
  listItemDone: {
    borderRadius: "1em",
    "&,&:focus,&:hover": {
      backgroundColor: "#F6F6E8",
      textDecoration: "line-through"
    }
  },
```

However, the above prevents there from being any hover effect on "done" items, so you may instead want to do something more like:

```
  listItemDone: {
    borderRadius: "1em",
    "&,&:focus": {
      backgroundColor: "#F6F6E8",
      textDecoration: "line-through"
    },
    "&:hover": {
      textDecoration: "line-through"
    }
  },
```

This allows the hover background color of done items to still be `theme.palette.action.hover`. If you want the hover color to be different for done items, you can specify it explicitly along with the textDecoration.

There is one other detail to take care of. If you click a list item to put it in a "done" state and then click it again, it will not be in the "done" state anymore but it will have the `button` focus styles applied. In order to remove that focus styling, you also need the following:

```
  listItem: {
    borderRadius: "1em",
    "&,&:focus": {
      backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.paper // or whatever color you want this to be
    }
  },
```

Here is my modified version of your sandbox:

[image: Edit 5kv3j6r1xn]

Comment: Thank you for this wonderful answer! Now I really understand this much better.

Comment: You can also use the conditional rendering in Ryan's CodeSandbox to set default item (usually the first item) to be "focused" true as well. E.g. done.name == "List1" ? style1 : style2

Answer (score 2):

So I've tried to add **!important** to this styles and it started working as expected:

```
  listItemDone: {
    borderRadius: "1em",
    backgroundColor: "#F6F6E8 !important",
    textDecoration: "line-through !important"
  },
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/8zworv0omj).
It looks like this **material-ui** just **overrides** your styles (textDecoration and backgroundColor) **when you hover over** elements. Hope that helps.