# How to set selected and hover color of ListItem in Material UI?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

Can't get 'selected' or 'hover colors to work for `ListItem`. For selected tried setting its classes like:

```
<ListItem selected button key="home" classes={{ selected: classes.listItemSelected }}>
  <ListItemText primary="Hi"/>
</ListItem>
```

and then set the style like:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  listItemSelected:{
    backgroundColor: "#ff0000",
  },
}));
```

But it doesn't do anything, the 'selected' is described in the `ListItem` component API [here](https://mui.com/api/list-item).

How do you get to set the color of both the **selected** and **hover** for `ListItem`?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Below is the portion of the [default ListItem styles](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.9.12/packages/material-ui/src/ListItem/ListItem.js#L29) that deals with the background color:

```
export const styles = (theme) => ({
  /* Styles applied to the (normally root) `component` element. May be wrapped by a `container`. */
  root: {
    '&$focusVisible': {
      backgroundColor: theme.palette.action.selected,
    },
    '&$selected, &$selected:hover': {
      backgroundColor: theme.palette.action.selected,
    },
    '&$disabled': {
      opacity: 0.5,
    },
  },
  /* Pseudo-class applied to the `component`'s `focusVisibleClassName` prop if `button={true}`. */
  focusVisible: {},
  /* Styles applied to the inner `component` element if `button={true}`. */
  button: {
    transition: theme.transitions.create('background-color', {
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.shortest,
    }),
    '&:hover': {
      textDecoration: 'none',
      backgroundColor: theme.palette.action.hover,
      // Reset on touch devices, it doesn't add specificity
      '@media (hover: none)': {
        backgroundColor: 'transparent',
      },
    },
  },
  /* Pseudo-class applied to the root element if `selected={true}`. */
  selected: {},
});
```

The important thing to notice is that the selected styling is done via a combination of two classes (`root` and `selected`), so if you try to override it using a single class you will not have sufficient [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity).

Below is an example showing one way to override the selected and hover states:

```
import React from "react";
import { makeStyles, withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import List from "@material-ui/core/List";
import MuiListItem from "@material-ui/core/ListItem";
import ListItemIcon from "@material-ui/core/ListItemIcon";
import ListItemText from "@material-ui/core/ListItemText";
import Divider from "@material-ui/core/Divider";
import InboxIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Inbox";
import DraftsIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Drafts";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    width: "100%",
    maxWidth: 360,
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.paper
  }
}));

const ListItem = withStyles({
  root: {
    "&$selected": {
      backgroundColor: "red",
      color: "white",
      "& .MuiListItemIcon-root": {
        color: "white"
      }
    },
    "&$selected:hover": {
      backgroundColor: "purple",
      color: "white",
      "& .MuiListItemIcon-root": {
        color: "white"
      }
    },
    "&:hover": {
      backgroundColor: "blue",
      color: "white",
      "& .MuiListItemIcon-root": {
        color: "white"
      }
    }
  },
  selected: {}
})(MuiListItem);

export default function SelectedListItem() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [selectedIndex, setSelectedIndex] = React.useState(1);

  const handleListItemClick = (event, index) => {
    setSelectedIndex(index);
  };

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <List component="nav" aria-label="main mailbox folders">
        <ListItem
          button
          selected={selectedIndex === 0}
          onClick={(event) => handleListItemClick(event, 0)}
        >
          <ListItemIcon>
            <InboxIcon />
          </ListItemIcon>
          <ListItemText primary="Inbox" />
        </ListItem>
        <ListItem
          button
          selected={selectedIndex === 1}
          onClick={(event) => handleListItemClick(event, 1)}
        >
          <ListItemIcon>
            <DraftsIcon />
          </ListItemIcon>
          <ListItemText primary="Drafts" />
        </ListItem>
      </List>
      <Divider />
      <List component="nav" aria-label="secondary mailbox folder">
        <ListItem
          button
          selected={selectedIndex === 2}
          onClick={(event) => handleListItemClick(event, 2)}
        >
          <ListItemText primary="Trash" />
        </ListItem>
        <ListItem
          button
          selected={selectedIndex === 3}
          onClick={(event) => handleListItemClick(event, 3)}
        >
          <ListItemText primary="Spam" />
        </ListItem>
      </List>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit ListItem selected and hover]

Related answers:

- [How to overried the selected classes in menuItem in material ui REACTjs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55446073/how-to-overried-the-selected-classes-in-menuitem-in-material-ui-reactjs/55447634#55447634)
- [How to change the styles of ListItem element with the "onclick" event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54497327/how-to-change-the-styles-of-listitem-element-with-the-onclick-event/54498689#54498689)

Comment: How about the ListItemIcon? I noticed that it doesn't change color with the text. How would I go about changing the ListItemIcon color as well?

Comment: @blah I've updated my example to change the icon color as well.

Comment: @RyanCogswell super useful example. Can you point to an explanation? I had originally missed the `selected: {}` and it didn't work. Fairly new to React and Mui, but very curious how that works... or where it's documented.

Comment: `"&:hover":` oh duh, so obvious.... /s

thanks for the tip

Answer (score 29):

You can use the [`sx`](https://mui.com/system/the-sx-prop/#main-content) prop in **MUI v5**:

```
<List
  sx={{
    // selected and (selected + hover) states
    '&& .Mui-selected, && .Mui-selected:hover': {
      bgcolor: 'red',
      '&, & .MuiListItemIcon-root': {
        color: 'pink',
      },
    },
    // hover states
    '& .MuiListItemButton-root:hover': {
      bgcolor: 'orange',
      '&, & .MuiListItemIcon-root': {
        color: 'yellow',
      },
    },
  }}
>
```

Or [`styled`](https://mui.com/system/styled/#main-content) to create a styled component that can be reused multiple times:

```
import MuiList from '@mui/material/List';

const List = styled(MuiList)({
  // selected and (selected + hover) states
  '&& .Mui-selected, && .Mui-selected:hover': {
    backgroundColor: 'red',
    '&, & .MuiListItemIcon-root': {
      color: 'pink',
    },
  },
  // hover states
  '& .MuiListItemButton-root:hover': {
    backgroundColor: 'orange',
    '&, & .MuiListItemIcon-root': {
      color: 'yellow',
    },
  },
});
```

### Live Demo

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

Comment: The great solution, thanks.

Comment: What does the double ampersand do?