# Any cost to using `makeStyles` in a component that will be iterated (like a list item)?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I've got a component that's only ever going to be rendered as part of a list. Let's call it `MyListItem`. The easiest thing from a coding perspective is to localize the `const useStyles = makeStyles(...)` right inside `MyListItem`. But in that case, if there are 100 list items, then I'm potentially invoking `useStyles` 100 times.

Normally, I'd just say screw it and put the `useStyles` in the parent (e.g. `MyList`) and then pass `classes` down to `MyListItem`. That way, `useStyles` is only computed once, rather than 100 times.

However, `MyListItem` could get invoked by more than 1 parent (e.g. `MyListOne`, `MyListTwo`). That means that any parent that wants to invoke `MyListItem` needs to contain the styles for `MyListItem`, which is less than ideal.

So here's the question: is Material-UI smart at all about detecting that the same `useStyles` is being invoked again and again? Will it really write out 100 versions of those styles, or will it collapse all those down at runtime? My guess is the answer is "no", but I figured it was worth asking.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Material-UI is definitely smart in this regard. If it wasn't, you would have the same problem with Material-UI's components such as `ListItem`. So long as `makeStyles` is being called at the top-level (which is the typical pattern) such that you are always using the exact same `useStyles` function, you are fine. A component that uses styles has more overhead than one that doesn't, but it won't duplicate the styles in the DOM.

The smarts in the library can be found here: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.9.13/packages/material-ui-styles/src/makeStyles/makeStyles.js#L56

```
let sheetManager = multiKeyStore.get(stylesOptions.sheetsManager, stylesCreator, theme);
```

This is the cache lookup for a particular style sheet. `stylesOptions.sheetsManager` will always [be the same](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.9.13/packages/material-ui-styles/src/StylesProvider/StylesProvider.js#L18) unless you are customizing it (very uncommon) for part of your component hierarchy using `StylesProvider`. `stylesCreator` is the argument to `makeStyles` -- i.e. the declaration of your styles. So for the same `makeStyles` call and the same theme, it will find the same styles and avoid re-generating them.

You can easily verify this is all working as intended by looking at the `<style>` elements in the `<head>` of your document via developer tools. The image below is from [this page](https://y5cvy.csb.app/) which is a sandbox for [this other StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61486061/how-to-set-selected-and-hover-color-of-listitem-in-material-ui/61486779#61486779).

[image: styles in head]

You can see in the image `style` elements for the different Material-UI components used in the page (e.g. MuiSvgIcon, MuiListItem, etc.). You can also see one generated from `makeStyles` and one generated from `withStyles`. The `withStyles` case is similar to what you are describing -- it is styles for a `ListItem` component that is used multiple times in the page, but the styles only occur once in the document.

Comment: When you say `makeStyles` called "at the top level", do you mean at the top level of the `MyListItem` component? e.g. within `MyListItem.tsx` it looks like this:  `const useStyles = makeStyles(...); const MyListItem = () => { const classes = useStyles(); ...};`?

Comment: Without seeing the full file, it's difficult to be certain you aren't misunderstanding, but I just mean not nested in another function or block (i.e. not inside your component function).

Comment: Another way to say it, is that the particular `makeStyles` call should get executed only once (when your component file is first imported) during the life of your application, not once for every render or once for every place you use the component.

Comment: Every example in the documentation follows this pattern of `makeStyles` being called at the top-level within its file, so I would be surprised if you don't already have your `makeStyles` call at the "top-level".

Comment: @hairbo I've added some information to the end of my answer about how to verify that the styles aren't being duplicated.

Comment: Yeah, I think I get it. So long as the `const useStyles = makeStyles()` is not created inside the `MyListItem` component, then MUI should be smart about caching. That makes sense, and that's the way I've been doing things all along.

FWIW, I wound up deciding to pass `classes` down from the `MyList` parent for this particular use-case, but it's good to know I can locate the style declarations within a component that will be iterated without incurring a huge performance hit. Thanks!!