# Material UI - Multiple css classes on global theme

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I'm using Material UI with React for the first time. I want to change my global theme, but what I want to change has two classes:

```css
.MuiListItem-root.Mui-selected, .MuiListItem-root.Mui-selected:hover {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
}
```

How can I select them with `createMuiTheme`? I've tried this:

```js
createMuiTheme({
  overrides: {
    MuiListItem: {
      root: {
        Mui: {
          selected: {
            backgroundColor: "black",
            "&:hover": {
              backgroundColor: "blue",
            },
          },
        },
      },
    },
  }
})
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: It won't work in that way, see https://material-ui.com/api/list-item/#css there is a selected rule name for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the correct syntax:

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  overrides: {
    MuiListItem: {
      root: {
        "&.Mui-selected": {
          backgroundColor: "black",
          "&:hover": {
            backgroundColor: "blue"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

[image: Edit style selected list item]

It is also equivalent to do:

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  overrides: {
    MuiListItem: {
      root: {
        "&$selected": {
          backgroundColor: "black",
          "&:hover": {
            backgroundColor: "blue"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

[image: Edit style selected list item (forked)]

Answer (score 1):

Just try this code

```
createMuiTheme({
    overrides: {
        MuiListItem: {
            root: {
                '&$selected': {
                    backgroundColor: "black"
                },
                '&$selected:hover'{
                    backgroundColor: "blue"
                }
            },
        },
    },
})
```

and look to this [response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61486061/how-to-set-selected-and-hover-color-of-listitem-in-material-ui)

Answer (score 0):

Material UI adds the global `Mui-selected` classes to make it easier to change specific elements globally.

However, you should just be targeting the `MuiListItem` classes according to the docs like so:

```
createMuiTheme({
  overrides: {
    MuiListItem: {
      selected: {
        backgroundColor: "black",
        "&:hover": {
          backgroundColor: "blue",
        },
      },
    },
  }
})
```

I see that this doesn't work anymore in the current version of Material UI. In the [source code](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/b0e10a1805ad7abd6f3c368bfbf63f4d85d29b47/packages/material-ui/src/ListItem/ListItem.js#L28) of the ListItem component, it is now defined like so:

```
  root: {
    '&$selected, &$selected:hover': {
      backgroundColor: theme.palette.action.selected,
    },
    ...
  }
```